# Bootstrap header is disappearing for desktop version

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Commented the code, different tricks, everything!

I have a website with multiple language versions. And for only one specific language, the header is disappearing , no matter what page are you in. For all the other versions (languages) the header is there, looking fine.

One important thing to mention is that if you shrink the screen or access it from a mobile device, it looks good!

Here is the German version of the page, and everything looks fine:

https://de.mynetmoto.com/shop.cfm/motorradreifen.html

Here is the Estonian version, and the header is disappearing:

https://ee.mynetmoto.com/shop.cfm/mootorratta-rehvid.html

Can you help me figure out what is different here?

Answer (score 0):

In your estony version you have visible classes on your nav-tag instead of the hidden classes in german version.

So in estony the nav is only visible for xs and sm screen size.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I am comparing the sources and see no difference.

Comment: The first nav. In Estony it has "<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top visible-xs visible-sm" id="jmHeaderMobile">" and in german it is "<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="jmHeader">" ... I saw it in the dev-tools and not the plain sourcecode. So if your sourcecode is the same maybe some javascript is setting these classes

Answer (score 0):

In English your header-bar is:

`<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top visible-xs visible-sm" id="jmHeaderMobile">`.

In the other languages it shows:

`<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="jmHeader">`

There are two differences here; the classes and the ID. The classes (`visible-xs visible-sm`) make it possible the menu is disappearing on the English version.

Comment: This code shows in both versions at line 328: `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top visible-xs visible-sm" id="jmHeaderMobile">` This code shows in both version at line 282: `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="jmHeader">` It is a dynamic website, it has the same HTML code, the same CSS...

Comment: Can you post both HTML files using https://www.diffchecker.com/ and store for 1 or 2 hour? So we can check both HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

When my customer translated the text inserted the following statement:

`You have to create an account so you can benefit of all myNETmoto
advantages.div></div>`

Notice the ending `div></div>` left there...

That messed everything! Thank you much for your help!

Comment: I was writing my reply with the same thing ha! Good job you found it too!